# Understanding Tabulation in Rel Category

Tags: category-theory

[*Tabulation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_(category_theory)#Maps_in_allegories.2C_and_tabulations) in Allegories is a structure that is defined over the diagram $A \rightarrow B$. In a concrete Allegory, namely Rel category (Category of Sets and Relations) this seems to be the reification of a relation (specifying a relation as a span.)

**My Question:**

In Rel category, is *Tabulation* and *limit* over the diagram $A \rightarrow B$ are the same thing? if they are not, how they are related?

---

**Update:**

As @Berci commented they are the same thing (probably somebody would add demonstration of this).

**As a following question**, what are the set of logical fomula (FOL possibly), that characterizes such a limit (up to isomorphism) in Rel category for the shape  $A \rightarrow B$.

Comment: Yes, they are the same things.